# Slack integration keeps failing and telling me not to worry about it

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

A Slack integration has been failing on me in SO for Teams:

> We experienced a problem with your Slack integration. No worries
>   though. Double-check what you would like to be notified about and try
>   again

I've been trying again for 36 hours. Any thoughts on what else I can try?

The Slack workspace is a new empty one set up just for this purpose. I'm also a member of some unrelated Slack workspaces, but this does not appear to play a role in the error.

Eventually I got this variant:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded
>   and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so at our feedback site,
>   https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hey! Our team is looking into this. Would you be open to sending this request to teams-support [at] stackoverflow? This will allow us to get more information on what Team you're in, dig into the specifics, and request data access as needed.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks an error message shouldn't say *oops, no worries, it's our mistake but we won't fix it*, even if that's supposed to be funny?

Comment: I agree with @DonQuiKong - this seems like a bit of a blasé and inappropriate response to something legitimately failing.

Comment: @ChanceHeath Hi Chance, sure I will

Comment: @DonQuiKong You guys make a good point there.  Those messages are the same ones we've had on the public site for a while (and follow our general tone there) but we might need to reconsider whether we need a different tone for things like that on a paid product.

Comment: @DonQuiKong You are not. But it is actually commonly recommended to do that, e.g. here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/53326/86764 and here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/39108/86764. Well _we won't fix it_ is not recommended.

Comment: @SørenD.Ptæus it's not about the "oops", it's about the *haha, you paid for this product but we don't care that it isn't working*

Comment: @DonQuiKong "Ooops" I omitted the worst part, _won't fix_.Both things are bad style imho, but won't fix is arguably a lot worse.

Comment: @DonQuiKong: I don't see the part where they say that they don't care if the product works or that they won't fix it. Yes, there's the tongue-in-cheek "we even try to fix some of them" bit, but it seems to me to overall be a statement that explicitly reporting the bug is unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexMiller I think that's definitely a good idea. In fact I think the public site should follow suit and be less cutesy and more matter-of-fact/informative with error messages.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think we all know that it's a joke, but if I'm annoyed by a recurring bug, especially in a paid product, I don't want jokes, I want fixes. Especially, I don't want someone joking that they won't fix it. In my opinion, it's just not funny. And apparently, I'm not the only one. However, I fully understand you might see it differently - after all, humor is subjective. But, again, my opinion, one should err on the side of caution there.